# Disable print option in ssrs url used in .net

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, reporting-services

I am using MVC .net application to display SSRS reports. In the view page, I am giving the SSRS Launch url inside the frame. A new requirement is to remove the print and export buttons from the toolbar. I saw that this can be achieved by using Report Viewer(RV) commands, but RV commands are not working if I add in the url.

On the other hand,I tried RS and RC commands, they are working fine. But to remove these buttons, I need RV command. Can anyone suggest a solution?

**My SSRS url looks like below:**
http:///Reports/report/FinanceReports/FINANCE_Launch_RPT?rs:Embed=True